# I'm trying to take the full list of followers on Twitter of each US Senator starting from a database and using rtweet

Tags: r, rtweet

Starting from a data frame containing the full list of usernames of the US Senators, I'm trying to take the full list of their followers using **rtweet 0.7.0 version** and the function **get_followers** with the retryonratelimit option set TRUE. If I use the column of the data frame R gives me an error:

```
Error in get_followers_(user = c("LisaMurkowski", "SenDanSullivan", "SenTuberville",  : 
  isTRUE(length(user) == 1) it's not TRUE
```

While if I just use one user name with the same option, it gives me just 5000 users and not the full list.

Using the last version of **rtweet** gives me the same problem in both cases.

```
library(rtweet)
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep=";")
follower <- get_followers(data$twitter, retryonratelimit = T)
```

```
library(rtweet)
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep=";")
follower <- get_followers("LisaMurkowski", retryonratelimit = T)
```

I tried those two chunks with both versions of rtweet but I failed to find a solution.

The function lookup_users says that there are 57271024 accounts (the sum of the number of followers of each US Senator). I would like to have this full list to build a network.

Comment: Maybe `follower <- lapply(data$twitter, get_followers, retryonratelimit = TRUE)`

Comment: It seems to be better, but it gives me just 5000 followers for each account, while every 16 rows it gives me nothing. I mean, there are 93 accounts with a tibble with 5000 rows and 7 accounts with zero rows. I hope I explained myself well.

Comment: Do the [twitter scraping limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api) apply?

Comment: I think yes. But it is the first time that I use this package, so I could have done some mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug in the pagination for multiple users in get_followers. This should be fixed in rtweet 1.1.0